# Почему происходит конфликт только с этого момента при git rebase master?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-branch

Делаю "git rebase master" находясь в ветке d, на рисунке ниже схема и текст файла

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- комит k1 для строки k1 на 8 позиции
- комит k2 для строки k2 на 9 позиции
- комит k3 для строки k3 на 10 позиции
- комит k4 для строки k4 на 11 позиции

ветка d начиналась с комита k3

Почему если сделать изменения до строчки 8 включительно и даже сдвинуть с 9 строчки текст вниз как на рисунке выше и перебазировать, конфликт не возникает, а если после например "k2 d 2" на 9 позиции то возникает?

на этом видео говорится что git должен посмотреть разницу начиная с k3, но по факту комит k2 тоже важен для rebase
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Du7Ay5o-Png&list=PLDyvV36pndZHkDRik6kKF6gSb0N0W995h&index=59

Comment: ну не смог он применить изменения. Можно конечно попробовать угадать, но смысл?

Comment: [user:2739] что угадать?

Comment: посмотреть на diff этих коммитов и угадать, почему git (а точнее утилита patch) не смогла сделать автоматический мердж и спровоцировала конфликт

Comment: @KoVadim вопрос о другом, почему k1 не нужен, а k2 нужен?

Comment: а разве состояния файла на момент коммита k3 не содержит  изменения комvита k2?

Comment: @KoVadim а что это должно значить?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109193/discussion-between--and-kovadim).

Comment: не пользуюсь чатами.

Comment: @KoVadim можно без чата, это stack просто

Comment: @KoVadim сделал тоже самое, но не по одной строчке изменил файл, а по 4, т.е комит k3 имеет 4 строчки, и вот странность, если изменить вторую строчку k3 то нет конфликта, а если третью строчку то есть, хотя комит k4 имеет изменения из k3

Comment: В смысле? Всё же очевидно. У вас есть расстояние (по умолчанию 3) контекста, вот и считайте. Можно сокращать расстояние, можно применять разные стратегии разрешения конфликтов... Читайте ProGit, там всё это разжёвано.